# Using GL driver and VNC shows "Unable to connect to desktop"

Tags: vnc, raspbian-buster

I need to enable GL driver on my RPI 3, But when I try to connect to it using RealVNC with GL driver on, it says unable to connect to the desktop, but my Pi is running fine when I hook it to my monitor.

Comment: Are you using the latest Raspbian Buster fully updated?

Comment: yep i ran sudo apt-get update and upgrade it and said only scratch had a new version